3-bit subtractor using full adders in logisim. Store results in a d-flipflop
Trying to build the circuit of a 3 - bit subtractor using Full Adders in Logisim. Then store the results in a D - Flipflop.
This is the circuit I have attempted to build but I am a little out of my element.
Can you show me the full circuit in logisim?

what use is a yes answer to you? ... please ask about the problem, not about people's ability ... never gives me any output, that's not possible, there is always an output, unless output wires are disconnected

"After you"… Please show the design you have a problem with. How did you establish it never gives me any output?

Looks almost done, if containing circuitry the description does not seem to call for: Where do you see a problem?

Assuming the problem to be fixed is the bit length mismatch, you need to select each adder and change the "Data Bits" to one:

